# Как установить драйвер mysql для php5.4 в isp manager?

Tags: php, debian, ispmanager

Немного вводной: 
Сервер Debian 10, установлен isp manager

Есть несколько версий php php7.4 как основная, php7.2 и php5.4 для двух очень старых проектов на битриксе(которые нет возможности обновить)

Сервер новый, только настроил и мигрирую на него проекты. Миграция Происходит с подобного сервера, там стоит Debian 9 и isp.

Проблема в том, что в списке расширений для php5.4 нет mysql.

пробовал взять файлик mysql.so из /opt/php54/lib/modules старого сервера и положить в тот же каталог на новом (создав mysql.ini в php.d)

Но при перезапуске php-fpm54 драйвер mysql не работает

service php-fpm54 status

выдает

[29-Mar-2020 00:22:14] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php54/lib/php/modules/mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.18:

Может кто сталкивался с схожей проблемой или знает, как это решить, очень на вас рассчитываю!

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, не так, как хотелось бы: 
снес все к чертям кошачьим, поставил debian9 и в списке расширений для php5.4 есть mysql
Придется оставаться на на девятке